# jQuery custom plugin changes applied to all instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created this JavaScript function it works if I use it for 1 gallery but if I use it for 2 it changes the gallery in the first one, I know I'm close but can't quite seam to figure out this last bit, do I need to use .each function?

```js
$.fn.holidayhomegallery = function() {

  $('.photo-thumbnails .thumbnail').click(function() {
    $('.photo-thumbnails .thumbnail').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    var path = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    $('.big-photo img').attr('src', path);
  });

  return this
}

$('.photo-other').holidayhomegallery();
```

```css
.gallery-photos {
  float: left;
}
.gallery-photos .big-photo {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-right: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0.8333333333%;
  padding-right: 0.8333333333%;
  float: left;
}
.gallery-photos .big-photo img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0.8333333333%;
  padding-right: 0.8333333333%;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 31%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail.current {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail.last {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail.thumbnail-inner {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="gallery-photos">
  <div class="big-photo">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=1" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div id="photo-abi" class="photo-thumbnails">
    <div class="thumbnail current">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=1" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=2" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=3" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=4" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail last ">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=5" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail last ">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=6" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="gallery-photos">
  <div class="big-photo">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=1" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div id="photo-abi" class="photo-thumbnails">
    <div class="thumbnail current">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=1" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=2" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=3" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=4" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail last ">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=5" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail last ">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=6" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the container class. As the main container have a class, inside the event handler, get this element and use this to get the other elements associated(are children of this container) with this instance.

So, instead of global selectors

```
$('.big-photo img').attr('src', path);
```

which will select all the matching elements on the page, use descendant selector with `find()`.

```
container.find('.big-photo img').attr('src', path)
```

**Code:**

```
$('.photo-thumbnails .thumbnail').click(function () {
    // Get the main container of the gallery
    var container = $(this).closest('.gallery-photos');

    // Use that container to get elements inside it
    container.find('.photo-thumbnails .thumbnail').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    var path = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

    // Use that container to get elements inside it
    container.find('.big-photo img').attr('src', path);
});
```

```js
$.fn.holidayhomegallery = function() {

  $('.photo-thumbnails .thumbnail').click(function() {
    var container = $(this).closest('.gallery-photos');
    container.find('.photo-thumbnails .thumbnail').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    var path = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    container.find('.big-photo img').attr('src', path);
  });

  return this;
};


$('.photo-other').holidayhomegallery();
```

```css
.gallery-photos {
  float: left;
}
.gallery-photos .big-photo {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-right: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0.8333333333%;
  padding-right: 0.8333333333%;
  float: left;
}
.gallery-photos .big-photo img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0.8333333333%;
  padding-right: 0.8333333333%;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 31%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail.current {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail.last {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail.thumbnail-inner {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery-photos .photo-thumbnails .thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="gallery-photos">
  <div class="big-photo">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=1" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div id="photo-abi" class="photo-thumbnails">
    <div class="thumbnail current">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=1" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=2" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=3" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=4" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail last ">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=5" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail last ">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=6" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="gallery-photos">
  <div class="big-photo">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=1" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div id="photo-abi" class="photo-thumbnails">
    <div class="thumbnail current">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=1" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=2" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=3" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=4" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail last ">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=5" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail last ">
      <div class="thumbnail-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/680x470/000000/fff&text=6" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Suggestion:**

```
$('.photo-thumbnails .thumbnail').click(function () {
    // Cache this instance
    var $this = $(this);
    // Get the main container of the gallery
    var container = $this.closest('.gallery-photos');

    // Select only the thumbnail elements having current class
    container.find('.photo-thumbnails .thumbnail.current').removeClass('current');
    $this.addClass('current');

    // Use that container to get elements inside it
    container.find('.big-photo img').attr('src', $this.find('img').attr('src'));
});
```